# TinyMCE link and code popups in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, tinymce-5

Is it possible to get a TinyMCE popup to go inside a Bootstrap modal? Not the actual editor itself but the popup for a link or code.  If so how do you do that?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If I had an example I would know how to do it lol

Comment: How about an example of what you have tried or a basic demo that you are looking at. You have provided no code whatsoever, so I am not sure how anyone is going to help.

Comment: Not sure the downvote is fair in this case. Tiny MCE's api is extremely detailed and I think the question is something like: "Where do I start?"

Comment: I've also been looking for a way of hooking into the popups, anchor tags in my case, and it is far from obvious how you start doing that

Comment: @twisty you and I both know me having a boil ate if any code is not going to help at all. This is for someone who actually knows about how to do this. I don’t even know if it’s possible.

Comment: @MikeFlynn it is very unclear what you want to have happen. Your statement contradicts your question. It sounds like if you have `<a href="https://google.com/">Link</a>` you want that to launch a popup with the URL loaded as the content of a TinyMCE editor inside of a Dialog. Is this the case or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @MikeFlynn you never mentioned or tagged Bootstrap in your post. Bootstrap is not jQuery UI. As you can customize TinyMCE in many ways, if anyone is going to help you, they need to see some amount of code or the options you are using to initialize TinyMCE. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes sorry, we were doing JQuery UI and since I posted this went to Bootstrap modals so I apologize.  I cant post code that I dont now exists or not.  Think about that.

Comment: @MikeFlynn I guess we'll never know... https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/bootstrap/

Comment: @MikeFlynn Ok, I see what you are wanting to have happen now. Can you give an example popup, or feature, that you would see a popup from TinyMCE as an example to test with. I will have to build an example.

Comment: @MikeFlynn found this article that I think discusses the topic of what you want: http://blog.offbeat-pioneer.net/index.php?page=articles&slug=TinyMCE-Create-a-plugin-using-bootstrap-modal-to-build-a-custom-dialog Also have a basic test example coming together.

Comment: Oh wow nice find there, surprised I didnt find it.  I maybe able to take it from there unless you have something you want to post an answer with.

Comment: @Twisty You should post an answer using that.  It's basically just "editor.addButton" onclick: open bootstrap dialog

Comment: @MikeFlynn no, I am good. I was looking at `editor.on("OpenWindow")` and was working on adding the Bootstrap classes to the Dialog. I was able to add the classes when a random dialog was opened by TinyMCE, yet there was some Styling conflict causing it not to work any better.

Comment: @user120242 that totally works but does nothing for TinyMCE's native dialog windows. I wanted to Skin/Theme the dialog to use Bootstrap CSS so that a native dialog window would look like part of Bootstrap. In this way, OP would not need to add custom buttons, but instead the `code` dialog would look like a Bootstrap dialog with the Code content from TinyMCE.

Comment: My Test Fiddle if you're curious what I was doing: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/w85jkuay/45/

Comment: @Twisty Oh, you mean hooking into the already existing editor.windowManager dialogues and having them embed into a bootstrap dialogue?  MikeFlynn Is that what you meant?  Probably should clarify that.

Comment: Yes pretty much, would like to have control of the button styles, etc, but yes have the modals appear in a bootstrap modal.

Comment: I'll just leave this here if that's what you're going for.  You'd probably be monkey patching editor.windowManager.  It looks to be more trouble than it's worth:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/modules/tinymce/src/core/main/ts/ui/WindowManagerImpl.ts
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/modules/tinymce/src/core/main/ts/api/WindowManager.ts

Comment: I agree, looking at your guys code, its just a lot of custom stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've created an example https://jsbin.com/sevowetifi/1/edit?html,output

put `textarea` or target element into `.modal-body` of your modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <textarea>Next, use our Get Started docs to setup Tiny!</textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the jsfiddle for full functionality:
https://jsfiddle.net/ndxy1pqt/
There's problems with Stack's iframe sandbox and TinyMCE so the embedded demo isn't editable, but it shows the button launching Bootstrap modal feature.

It basically just entails adding a plugin, and using `editor.addButton` to add a button that launches Bootstrap.  You'll want to look in more details about Bootstrap plugins to do things like getting the right coordinates to create things like embedded tooltips or the like.  I'd go and look at a few TinyMCE plugins with custom toolbars for more information.

```js
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myPlugin', function (editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('launchModal', {
        text: 'My Bootstrap Modal',
        onclick: function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#modal-button').on('click',function(){
             editor.setContent('set content');
              editor.selection.setNode(editor.dom.create('img', {src: 'some.gif', title: 'some title'}));
            });
        }
    });
});
tinymce.init({
 selector: '#text-box',
 plugins: 'myPlugin',
 menubar: 'myPlugin',
 toolbar: "launchModal",
    templates: [
  { title: 'Template 1', description: 'Description of template 1', content: '<p>alma</p><p>korte</p>' },
  { title: 'Template 2', description: 'Description of template  2', content: 'development.html' }
    ],
    height: 300
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <textarea id="text-box"></textarea>
    
<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button id="modal-button">button
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```